# check if formgrup in formarray is valid angular 6 reactive form

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a functionality which add an input field on click of a button

```
addMilestoneRow() {
    if (this.milestoneFormArray.length === 0) {
      this.milestoneFormArray.push(this.initCreateMilestoneForm());
    } else {
      this.createGoalForm.controls['milestones']['controls'].forEach(value => {
        if (value.valid) {
          this.milestoneFormArray.push(this.initCreateMilestoneForm());
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

the input field is a part of a form array which has its own formgroup

```
initCreateMilestoneForm(data?: Milestones) {
    return this.fb.group({
      title: [
        data ? data.title : null,
        [Utils.emptySpaceValidator(), Validators.required]
      ],
      completed: [{ value: data ? data.completed_at : false, disabled: false }],
      id: [{ value: data ? data.id : null }],
      status: [{ value: data ? data.status : 'PENDING' }],
      goal_id: [{ value: data ? data.goal_id : null }]
    });
  }
```

I want that whenever i click on the button it should check whether the input field previously added is valid or not 
for this i have used for each but the problem is if i have 3 fields previously added then and all are filled then due to for each it add 3 new blank fields but i want only 1 field to be added

can anyone help